# Consolidating a few React applications into one (using Next.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, webpack, next.js

I created an app using Next.js (with 5 simple pages). Also I have another React app (Other developers is working on it now). So my goal is include second React app into the first app (which is using Next.js). So if someone will go to "https://localhost:3000/app" url, the app must render second React app (localhost is just for example). I can integrate Express, but i can't setup routes to reach my goal. Also the second React app has it's own routing, so maybe there is some way to setup routing, to render page, but indicate another root folder:

```
app.get('/app', function(req, res){
  res.set('root-folder-for-app', '/app')
  res.send('/app/index');
});
```

Comment: maybe just use two folder is way faster and easier, or two different endpoints...

Comment: There's not really enough information here to answer your question. I think the simplest solution is going to be to just keep them as separate apps and use nginx or something if you want them to share the same domain. That, or drop express and make the second app play nice with Next.js.